# $\sin \alpha = \frac{3}{5} $ and $\cos \beta = -\frac{12}{13}$ . Find the values that $\cos(\alpha+\beta )$ can get.

Tags: trigonometry

$\sin \alpha = \frac{3}{5} $ and $\cos \beta = -\frac{12}{13}$ . Find the values that $\cos(\alpha+\beta )$ can get.

Here $0<\alpha < \frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}<\beta<\pi$.

Yes I can find a value for $\cos(\alpha+\beta )$ by using $\cos(\alpha+\beta )=\cos \alpha \cos \beta - \sin \alpha \sin \beta$

But are there more values that  $\cos(\alpha+\beta )$ can get ?

Comment: Do you mean $0 < \alpha < \frac{\pi}{2}$ and $0 < \beta < \pi$?

Comment: Why couldn't $\alpha$ be between $\pi/2$ and $\pi$ and $\beta$ between $\pi/2$ and $3\pi/2$?

Comment: The ranges  of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are irrelevant to this problem.

Comment: @HansEngler That's not true, if we have $\sin(\alpha)=\sin(\frac\pi2-\alpha)$, then you are implying $\cos(\alpha+\beta)=\cos(\frac\pi2-\alpha+\beta)$, which is not true.  Without the range, different values of $\alpha$ can affect the end result.

Comment: @SimpleArt Are you telling me that there are two different addition theorems for the cosine? One that I know and another one that I never heard of???

Comment: @HansEngler No, if you just use the regular addition formula, you will get $\sin(\alpha)=\sin(\frac\pi2-\alpha)$, but since the addition formula is different for $\cos$, it won't be the same, and we will have different value for $\cos(\alpha+\beta)$ this way.  (Note, before the OP stated that $\alpha,\beta>0$.

Comment: @SimpleArt You are confusing me. $\sin \alpha = \sin (\pi - \alpha)$ is simply a symmetry property of the sine and has nothing to do with addition formulae, whether they are "regular" or not (what would that be? irregular?). When you write "it won't be the same", what exactly are you talking about? What will be different? I am sure we both agree that one can only get different values of $\cos (\alpha + \beta)$ if either $\alpha$ or $\beta$ or both are changed.

Comment: @HansEngler Yes, that is pretty much what I'm saying.  Sorry if it was confusing.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just draw a diagram of the unit circle? $\alpha$ is a first quadrant angle, and $\beta$ is a second quadrant angle .... reason it though from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have two well-known Pythagorean triples:
$$3^2+4^2=5^2 ,\qquad 5^2+12^2=13^2\tag{1}$$
hence $\sin\alpha=\frac{3}{5}$ and $0\leq\alpha\leq\frac{\pi}{2}$ implies $\cos\alpha=\frac{4}{5}$, as well as $\cos\beta=-\frac{12}{13}$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}\leq\beta\leq\pi$ implies $\sin\beta=\frac{5}{13}$. So, by the cosine sum formula:
$$ \cos(\alpha+\beta)=\cos\alpha\cos\beta-\sin\alpha\sin\beta = -\frac{48}{65}-\frac{15}{65}=\color{red}{-\frac{63}{65}.}\tag{2}$$

Answer (score 3):

Since $\sin$ is a monotone increasing function on the interval $(0,\frac\pi2)$, and since $0<\frac35<1$, then we know, that there can only be one value of $\alpha$ in this interval for which $\sin(\alpha)=\frac35$, since $\sin$ will only take that value once.

Since $\cos$ is a monotone decreasing function on the interval $(0,\pi)$ and since $-1<-\frac{12}{13}<1$, we know that there can only be one value of $\beta$, since $\cos$ will only take that value once in the interval.

Thus, there can only be one $\cos(\alpha+\beta)$, since there can only be one unique $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Answer (score 0):

The formula for $\cos(\alpha + \beta)$ tells you how to compute this from $\cos \alpha, \sin \alpha, \cos \beta, \sin \beta$. You already know two of these numbers. The other two are not specified, but since $\cos^2 \gamma + \sin^2 \gamma = 1$ for any $\gamma$, there are not too many choices for each of these. And you know something about the ranges of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ which should help you narrow it down further.

I hope you can take it from there.